# Concat selector nightwatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

I need to do this but i can´t: 
I create a selector:

```
lastUrl: {
  selector: ' span.pull-right.desp > i.open-filter.img-icon.pull-xs-right'
},
```

And I try to do this:

```
this.click('#conf-tab-3 > @lastUrl');
```

Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: what is #conf-tab-3

Comment: check this : https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/821